# Does a fully mechanical heat pump make sense?

Tags: heat-transfer, renewable-energy, energy-storage

Is it reasonable to operate a fully mechanical heat pump? For example, using a linear back-and-forth motion from a vortex bladeless turbine to operate a mechanical compressor to heat (or cool off) a sizeable container of water?

Comment: What does "fully mechanical" actually mean in this context? Are you just talking about a conventional AC except that the electric motor is replaced by something else? Like a waterwheel?

Comment: @DKNguyen I mean without using electrical power at all (e.g. to operate the compressor) and just using mechanical power to heat or cool water.

Comment: Then sure why not? Like I said, waterwheel. Some methods will obviously be more practical than others. For a trivial example: if a hydroelectric dam can turn turbines to power an entire city there's no reason it couldn't directly turn a compressor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtually every possible way of doing this is already out there.

For bolt-ons, you can find propshaft pto chain drives and belt drives, hydraulic and mechanical engine pto systems, and front of block bolt-ons that are fan belt driven or bolted to the propshaft head.

Stand alone systems are available from suitecase sized to boxcar sized.

https://www.yanmar.com/global/energy/ghp/

We expect that you do some research before you ask here. Any google search will give you many examples. There are millions of these out there used where shaft power is readily available (like on ships) or where electricity is scarce or sketchy.

Some references for further research.

> Sanaye et al. (2010) analysed a GHP for the Iranian climate conditions and found that  depending on climate and demand, annual operating costs (which is also dependent  on energy price) for EHPs were higher than that GHPs. They also found that GHPs were more economical than EHPs in  the  residential  sector.  Even  GHP  air  conditioning  systems  compared  to  the  same  kind  of  EHP  air conditioning system were more economical (Lian et al., 2005) . Engine driven heat pump systems have been used for different industrial applications (Gungor et al., 2011) but few studies have been done on domestic applications of an engine driven heat pump. Hepbasli  et al. (2009) performed a review  and mathematical modelling for GHP  systems for  residential and industrial applications. Various  applications and  different arrangements of GHP have been discussed. They found GHP systems are more efficient when used for both water and space heating.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269393425_A_REVIEW_OF_DIESEL_ENGINE_DRIVEN_HEAT_PUMPS_DEHPs_AND_THEIR_POTENTIAL_IN_THE_UK_DOMESTIC_SECTOR